# Find second (or n) highest value of a field in a vector of object c++

Tags: c++, object, vector, iterator, field

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766136/how-to-get-min-or-max-element-in-a-vector-of-objects-in-c-based-on-some-field), I asked how to get the value of the max element in a vector of objects in c++ based o some field of said objects. I extended the algorithm to get the index of that max element so I could later just pop it from the vector of object.

Here is the code that I use right now and it works fine:

```
vector<MyOwnClass> scoretracker // MyOwnClass has a ".score" field

// Some code filling scoretracker

auto max = std::max_element(scoretracker.begin(), scoretracker.end(),
    [] (const MyOwnClass &a, const MyOwnClass &b )
{
    return a.score < b.score; // I am not sure how this line works
});

int index = distance(scoretracker.begin(), max);
```

So, I tried to modify this to get the **second highest** (or n-th value) instead of the max but so far my attempts failed.

It makes me realize that I don't really understand why "return a.score < b.score" returns the highest value.

By looking at how max_element [works](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/), I am not sure if it could ever be used to find the 2nd largest.

Oh, finally, I would rather not pop_back the highest value from the vector, find the new max (the 2nd highest value in the original vector) and add some logic to restore the original version. Well if I have to, I'll do it but there might be some iterator property or something else I don't know...

Comment: Instead of `max_element`, you can just `std::sort`. Then you can just find the 1st, 2nd, or nth highest element just by indexing the sorted array (or a sorted copy if you want).

Comment: Ok I am trying some implementation right now!

Comment: `why "return a.score < b.score" returns the highest value`  That is a predicate to order the values.  What is done *after* the values are ordered is up to the algorithm.

Comment: @Cyber Ok I missed the last couple of words from your comment. If one does not want to break the ordering of the vector, simply sort a copy. I will look at how much time it eats in my process. Thanks!

Comment: Well if you look at the original question, I did not know at that time that it was a similar type of problem than the one in this possible duplicate. I thought I would have to modify max_elements... Well if this is really a duplicate someone could cast a duplicate vote, or maybe the mention at the beginning could be enough...

Comment: But what I like from the present question's answers is that they provide code adapted to c++, and they do not (necessarily) bother with keeping a O(n) complexity. So that's why I think this is not a duplicate, but it is only my humble opinion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
auto max = std::sort(scoretracker.begin(), scoretracker.end(),
    [] (const MyOwnClass &a, const MyOwnClass &b )
{
    return a.score < b.score;
});
```

then

```
scoretracker.back().score;
```

would give you last element

```
scoretracker.at(position).score;
```

would return element of the position where position can be any number

Comment: He does not have to sort whole sequence to get nth highest element, `std::nth_element` is sufficient

Comment: OMG is it available?? waoo, i dont know when m gona see everything now c++ provides. BTW thanks @Slava

Comment: Since this (std::sort) work in my case and that I am not able to use nth_element correctly, I will eventually mark this as a correct answer. But if someone shows me a working example with nth_element and that it is faster in my code, I will choose the fastest ^^

Answer (score 4):

If you need the index of only once (and not for all values), you may use:

```
std::size_t get_index_of_nth_greatest(const std::vector<MyOwnClass>& v, std::size_t k)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> indexes(v.size());
    std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0);

    std::nth_element(indexes.begin(), indexes.begin() + k, indexes.end(),
        [&](int lhs, int rhs)
        {
            return v[lhs].score > v[rhs].score;
        }
    );
    return indexes[k];
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/2chePe).

**Note**: As *Vlad from Moscow* points out, with duplicate inputs, there is no guaranty of the order of the duplicates, and so you may have identical indexes for different `k`.

Comment: I knew of `partial_sort`, so I figured something akin to `nth_element` must exist.

Comment: @Jarod42 It si a wrong solution because in general case elements of the cntainer can coincide.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The same index may be valid for several `k` (with duplicate) even if it is not intuitive (BTW, I got distinct indexes in this [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac10e48e07a9cec5)).

Comment: @Jarod42  I have not understood what you wrote however please answer the qestion what will be returned for sequence { 2, 2, 2, 1 } and k equal to 2?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Only for `k = 3` the expected index would be `3` with value `=1`. For k < 3, any index in `{0, 1, 2}` would be acceptable for me (with value `=2`).

Comment: @Jarod42 So we may resume that your solution is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more sophisticated approach you can look at the `std::partition` function.

std::partition takes a container and divides it into two parts.

```
std::vector<MyOwnClass> v(100);
// fill vector with stuff. Find n-th element.
auto mid = v[somwhere_in_the_middle];
auto p = std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                [mid](MyOwnClass v){ return v.score < mid.score; } );
```

Every element bigger than `p` is to the right of `p`. The smaller ones are to the left.
If you are looking for the second biggest, you go to the right as long as the distance of `v.end() - p` is large enough.

This method is called quick-select, based on the ideas of quicksort, and is detailed here [How to find the kth largest element in an unsorted array of length n in O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on).

And this is of course already implemented as `std::nth_element` and can be used as

```
std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin()+5, v.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

To get the 6th largest element at the 6th position.

Comment: Well reading on nth_element, this sounds like what I want. From what I understand, the `+5` denotes the position (counting from 0) of the wanted item. 
`auto p = std::nth_element(scoretracker.begin(), scoretracker.begin()+1, scoretracker.end(), std::greater<double>() );`

Strangely, there is an error saying that there is no member "greater" in std, which is seemingly no true (VS2012Pro, C++)

Comment: Ok I should add #include <functional> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567699/stdgreater-not-defined-in-msvc2012

Comment: @Doombot Yes, you need to give it the same comparison lambda as you are currently using. It does not know about your score member. Include <algorithm> too.

Comment: Ok what about the `somwhere_in_the_middle` from the partition code, whatever value I seem to use it returns the same thing into p. Also, I tried to fit the comparison lambda different ways but it all fails. So this mean I don't understand the lambda... -_-

Comment: OK now I used this: `std::nth_element(scoretracker.begin(), scoretracker.begin()+1, scoretracker.end(),
   [] (const MyOwnClass &a, const MyOwnClass &b )
  {
   return a.score > b.score;
  });`

and it sorts scoretracker from the biggest score to the lowest. It will be fine but it is like if I used sort?

Comment: @Doombot Almost. It orders the minimal sequence required. A sort is always going to be slower. If I understand you correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64893/discussion-between-doombot-and-captain-giraffe).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by taking the `max` element you already have and looking for the `std::max_element()` either side of it and getting the `std::max()` of those two values:

```
struct MyOwnClass
{
    int score = 0;
    MyOwnClass(int s): score(s) {}
};

vector<MyOwnClass> scores = {{4}, {2}, {7}, {9}, {3}}; 

int main()
{
    // we need this more than once
    auto compare = [] (const MyOwnClass &a, const MyOwnClass &b)
    {
        return a.score < b.score; // I am not sure how this line works
    };

    auto max = std::max_element(scores.begin(), scores.end(), compare);

    std::cout << "max: " << max->score << '\n';

    // call std::max_element() twice with ranges either side of the max element
    // and get the std::max() of those values
    auto next_max = std::max(std::max_element(scores.begin(), max, compare)->score
        , std::max_element(max + 1, scores.end(), compare)->score);

    std::cout << "next max: " << next_max << '\n';
}
```

**NOTE:** If you want to get the *third* or *fourth* elements this technique is a technique of diminishing returns, probably better to do a `std::sort()`.